# Can an ISO used with VirtualBox damage my PC?

Tags: virtualbox, virus, iso-image

I understand the concept of a virtual machine is that any malicious software run on the guest OS cannot affect the host OS, but if the ISO file itself contains some sort of virus, could it damage my PC?

In case it makes any difference, I'm running Windows 10 as the Host OS on my laptop, and I'm using Oracle Virtual Box.

Comment: If you separate the host and guest OS without an internal network, then guest OS may not harm host OS.

Comment: If you think that the iso is harmful, then you may change the extension of that ISO file (like abc.iso.bkp) so that you never mount it in Windows accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

If you have misconfigured your VirtualBox host, then yes.

You can set the network to bridge, which places the guest inside your network. The ISO then can access your network too, and wreck havoc.

If you set the network to NAT without opening ports in the VirtualBox NAT settings, then no, the ISO can only damage the virtual machine itself.

Comment: also if you mount the iso on the host and then connect the drive to the VM, autorun on the iso may get the opportunity to execute on the host. be sure to directly mount the ISO in VBox.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as answered, so others know you no longer need help.